# show layout every time the user enter the application after app has been killed from background

Tags: android

I would like to make a particular layout visible during the startup of an application, not when the activity startup every time the user is accessing the activity in the app, can someone tell me how to do that?

I have tried onstart() method and read so many answers but most answers are about background and foreground, they aren't what I want, onstart() keeps showing the layout every single time the activity was accessed.

I only wanted the layout to show one time when a user access the app from the phone (when app has been killed in background or when it is not previously in the background before/opened for the first time on that day for example). A one time thing, but not when the first time the app is used but every time the user enter the app (after the app is not in / deleted from background).

Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use SharedPreference and keep a flag and do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharedPrefences, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    SharedPreferences sp;
    Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     sp = getSharedPreferences("mypreference",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sp.edit();

  }

   @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //we set default value to true because if it's not initialized yet, it is first time!
    if(sp.getBolean("key_first_time" , true)){

     //it's app first time start up
     ....
     //change status of shared preference to false
     editor.putBoolean("key_first_time" , false);
     editor.apply();
    }else{

     //it's not app first time start up

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

  //this method called when your activity is not in memory anymore

 //change status of shared preference to true
 editor.putBoolean("key_first_time" , true);
 editor.apply();
}

}
```

> Note that when activity removed from android memory(background) our
>   sharedprefrence will change to true, in other word our first time
>   status will reset.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure why but the it still load every time the activity is started in that app, is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: hi , first question : has your problem solved? if yes so please explain with more detail our new problem and if no, so what is the problem? explain it with more details.thank you.@Lionlollipop

Comment: Hi, I put a toast to try and the problem is that it still show even when in the app moving from activity to activity :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple solution is just create the layout in same layout(Which you are using with activity)(both layout should covers full screen you can achieve this by relative layout) and set in XML visibility="Gone" for the layout you want to show for few seconds, now when activity start set the id.setVisibility=VIEW.VISIBLE for layout you want to show for few sec and set count-down for 3/4 sec and on countdown finish set id.setVisibility= VIEW.GONE,,
You have to use Relative Layout for this purpose, and another solution is you can use splash screen if your activity is Launcher Activity.